# Lein Midje :autotest throwing exception (No namespace found)

Tags: clojure, leiningen, midje

I am trying to setup autotest for midje. Currently, running lein midje works. However running lein midje :autottest gives me the stack trace below.

I run through my different namespaces and they all compile

```
Compiling 1 source files to /Users/oloo/Documents/work/cmp/target/classes

warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_6' from annotation processor 'org.sonatype.guice.bean.scanners.index.SisuIndexAPT6' less than -source '1.7'
1 warning

======================================================================
Loading (cmp.models cmp.util cmp.repository.orderdeliveryschedule-repository cmp.repository.facility-repository cmp.repository.facility-cycle-data-repository cmp.views.layout cmp.routes.facility cmp.repository.item-repository cmp.repository.procurement-plan-repository cmp.routes.login cmp.excel-util cmp.repository.district-repository cmp.repository.facility-order-repository cmp.repository.facility-issue-repository cmp.routes.import-data cmp.test-util cmp.routes.item cmp.routes.district cmp.repository.user-repository cmp.routes.reports cmp.repository.category-repository cmp.routes.facility-issue cmp.routes.procurement-plan cmp.routes.facility-order cmp.handler cmp.repl cmp.repository.level-repository)
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.mchange.v2.log.MLog).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: No namespace: cmp.routes.item found
    at clojure.core$the_ns.invoke(core.clj:3760) 
    at clojure.core$ns_name.invoke(core.clj:3767)  
    at midje.repl$on_require_failure.invoke(repl.clj:387)  
    at midje.data.project_state$require_namespaces_BANG_$broken_source_file_QMARK___5874.invoke(project_state.clj:65)  
    at midje.data.project_state$require_namespaces_BANG_$shorten_ns_list_by_trying_first__5877.invoke(project_state.clj:69)  
    at midje.data.project_state$require_namespaces_BANG_.invoke(project_state.clj:75)  
    at midje.data.project_state$react_to_tracker_BANG_$fn__5889.invoke(project_state.clj:98)  
    at midje.repl$namespace_stream_checker.invoke(repl.clj:403)  
    at midje.data.project_state$react_to_tracker_BANG_.invoke(project_state.clj:94)  
    at midje.data.project_state$mkfn_COLON_scan_and_react$fn__5893$fn__5894.invoke(project_state.clj:109)  
    at clojure.lang.Atom.swap(Atom.java:37)  
    at clojure.core$swap_BANG_.invoke(core.clj:2160)  
    at midje.data.project_state$mkfn_COLON_scan_and_react$fn__5893.invoke(project_state.clj:107)  
    at midje.data.project_state$load_everything.invoke(project_state.clj:117)  
    at midje.repl$autotest.doInvoke(repl.clj:511)  
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:397)  
    at midje.repl$autotest.doInvoke(repl.clj:524)  
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)  
    at user$eval6032.invoke(NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6619)  
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6609)  
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6582)  
    at clojure.core$eval.invoke(core.clj:2852)  
    at clojure.main$eval_opt.invoke(main.clj:308)  
    at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:327)  
    at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:362)  
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:440)  
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)  
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:419)  
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:163)  
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:532)  
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)  
Subprocess failed
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this: https://github.com/marick/Midje/issues/215

It says:

```
If a file being loaded by Midje at startup has a parse error (a reference to an unknown 
symbol, etc.) that prevents it from being loaded successfully, Midje swallows the original
load error and instead prints the following error, which is much less useful.
```

I have suffered from this too: any little typo brings up this misleading error message.

Comment: But shouldn't the non-autotest `lein midje` call have produced an exception then? OP noted that that one works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I remember having problems with autotest and namespaces that `:require` or `:use` other namespaces using the `[prefix ns1 ns2 ...]` form. So, the following did not work:

```
(ns abc
  (:use [abc def ghi]))
```

while this was okay:

```
(ns abc
  (:use abc.def
        abc.ghi))
```

Are you using that kind of syntax?